# Javascript case insensitive when comparing a letter in a word

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, case-insensitive

I'm have this exercise where a user enters a word then enters a letter to see how many times the letter appears in that word. This part of the project works just fine. However, I want to make it case insensitive, as of right now it's not. I thought creating a variable for uppercase and one for lowercase then comparing both of those variables to i or to the letter variable would work. However, it's making the counter double the amount of letters found in the word. Can someone help me? Here's my code:

```js
function checkWordAndLetter() {
  var userWord = $("#word").val();
  console.log(userWord);
  var userLetter = $("#letter").val();
  console.log(userLetter);
  var letterUpperCase = userLetter.toUpperCase();
  var letterLowerCase = userLetter.toLowerCase();
  var tally = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < userWord.length; i++) {
    if (userLetter == userWord[i] && i == letterUpperCase ||
      letterLowerCase) {
      tally++;
    }
  }
  console.log(tally);
  $("#letterResults").html(" There are " + tally + " " + userLetter + "'s  in the word " + userWord);
  console.log("apple");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainPage">
  <h2>Find the Letter in the Word</h2>
  <h4>Enter a word and select a letter to see how many times that letter appears in the word</h2>
    <p>Enter below:</p>
    <br/> Word:
    <input id="word" type="text" name="word"><br/><br/> Letter: <input id="letter" type="text" name="letter"><br/><br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <button id="submit" type="button" name="submit" onclick="checkWordAndLetter()">submit</button>
    <p id="letterResults"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest option here, *without changing the rest of your code*, is to upper (or lower) case *both* sides of the equation so you are comparing like for like.

```js
function checkWordAndLetter() {
  var userWord = $("#word").val();
  var userLetter = $("#letter").val();
  var userWordUpper = userWord.toUpperCase();
  var userLetterUpper = userLetter.toUpperCase();
  var tally = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < userWord.length; i++) {
    if (userLetterUpper == userWordUpper[i]) {
      tally++;
    }
  }
  $("#letterResults").html(" There are " + tally + " " + userLetter + "'s in the word " + userWord);
}
$("#word,#letter").change(checkWordAndLetter)

checkWordAndLetter();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='word' value='hello'/>
<input type='text' id='letter' value='l' />
<div id='letterResults'></div>
```

---

In your original code, this line:

```
if (userLetter == userWord[i] && i == letterUpperCase || letterLowerCase) {
```

could have been:

```
if (letterUpperCase == userWord[i] || letterLowerCase == userWord[i]) {
```

---

Another option might be to use `.split()` which separates the string into an array by breaking on the specified character.  Normally this would be `,`, but you can use any letter:

```
var tally = userWordUpper.split(userLetterUpper).length - 1;
```

```js
function checkWordAndLetter() {
  var userWord = $("#word").val();
  var userLetter = $("#letter").val();

  var userWordUpper = userWord.toUpperCase();
  var userLetterUpper = userLetter.toUpperCase();

  var tally = userWordUpper.split(userLetterUpper).length - 1;

  $("#letterResults").html(" There are " + tally + " " + userLetter + "'s in the word " + userWord);
}
$("#word,#letter").change(checkWordAndLetter)

checkWordAndLetter();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='word' value='hello' />
<input type='text' id='letter' value='l' />
<div id='letterResults'></div>
```

---

A further option would be use to a regex (edit: see Rory's answer, no need to repeat here) - the benefit of a regex is that you don't need to convert to upper/lower first.

Comment: Thank you so much. This really helped!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count how much a letter appears in a word case-insensitively, downcase the word *and* the letter before iterating through the word. In this way you will be comparing the same letters. Example:

```
let tally = 0;
let letter = "a";
let word = "cAaatttt";
word = word.toLowerCase();
letter = letter.toLowerCase();
for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    if (word[i] === letter) tally++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do what you require with your current code is to convert both the word and letter strings to match cases, then do the comparison. You can use `toLowerCase()` or `toUpperCase()` to do that.

However you can simplify the code even further than that by creating a Regular Expression and using the case-insensitivity flag (`i`) along with `match()`, like this:

```js
$('#submit').click(function() {
  var userWord = $("#word").val();
  var userLetter = $("#letter").val();
  
  var re = new RegExp(userLetter, 'gi');
  var tally = userWord.match(re).length;
  
  $("#letterResults").html(`There are ${tally} ${userLetter}'s  in the word ${userWord}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainPage">
  Word: <input id="word" type="text" name="word"><br/><br/> 
  Letter: <input id="letter" type="text" name="letter"><br/><br/>
  <button id="submit" type="button" name="submit">submit</button>
  <p id="letterResults"></p>
</div>
```

Also note the use of an unobtrusive event handler here instead of the outdated `on*` event attribute, which you should avoid using.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the word to lowercase and use the lowercase letter to check. You don't need to do `uppercase === letter || lowercase === letter`. Another issue is your if statement as others have pointed out already.

You could also use RegExp for this in one line:

```
const letter = 'a'
const word = 'pizza potatoes and hamburgers'
const reg = new RegExp(letter, 'gi')
const count = (word.match(reg) || []).length // 4, 0 if no letters found
```

Comment: Thank you very much